# $C^1$-foliation are absolutely continuous

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

I trying to figure out why this is result is true :

If $F$ is a $C^1$-foliation with $C^1$-leaves, then it is absolutely continuous, where *absolutely continuity* here means that given a foliation chart $(U,h)$ and $L$ some transversal, there exists a measurable family of positive measurable functions $j_x : F_U(x) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any measurable set $A \subset U$, we have that $m(A) = \int_L \int_{F_U(x)} \mathbb{1}_A(x,y)j_x(y)dm_{F(x)}(y)dm_L(x)$ where $m$ is our volume.

I've read that this is a direct application of Fubini Theorem, but since I don't know much about foliation and differential geometry, I don't really feel confident about this...

Any help is very greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT : this question has been put on hold because it lacks some context. So here it is. I'm interesting in proving that ergodicity of $C^2$ Anosov on compact riemannian manifold. I'm following Brin & Stuck *Introduction to dynamical systems*. The key idea of the proof is to prove that the stable/unstable foliation is absolutely continuous, as defined above. At one point, authors show that absolutely continuous implies transversely absolute continuity. To do that, they introduce some auxiliary foliation that is $C^1$, while explaining that it is *obviously* absolutely continuous and transversely absolutely continuous. I've read this in differents books/ressources, as a direct application of *Fubini theorem*. The context is pretty standard in DS, so maybe I should be posting this question of MO...

---

EDIT 2 : Some more context [here](https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2013/11/24/fubini-foiled/) (especially the line "...*basic results from calculus show that a version of Fubini’s theorem holds*..." This is precisely the claim for which I'm looking a proof. Since I'm working only on the torus, it might goes like this :

Let $F$ a $C^1$ foliation with $C^1$-leaves on the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$, with $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure. Let $U$ a foliation chart. Then, for any $E \subset U \subset \mathbb{T}^2$ measurable, we have : $\lambda(E) = \int_L \int_{F_U(x)} \mathbb{1}_E(x,y)\delta_x(y) dm_{F(x)(y)} dm_L(x)$ with $L$ any local transversal and $(\delta_x)_x$ a family of positive measurable functions.

Comment: Should I consider posting this on MO ? Some professor at my lab had not really a clue on how to do that...It seems to be part of some *folkore* : this has been proved on rare occasions, so we just need to find the right reference...

Comment: Indeed, it is an immediate application of Fubini's theorem **after** making a coordinate change as in the flow box theorem (use implicit function theorem). Quite unlikely to find an explicit proof written since it is really immediate. Problems only occur when the foliation is not smooth (which is the typical case...).